# Jquery tweet timeframe parameter

Tags: jquery

Here are a list of parameters the JQuery Tweet plugin takes.
http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/jquery.tweet.js
I need to retrieve a list of tweets that only mention a certain word going back up to 4-5 weeks, how do i inrincrease the timeframe in which the plugin pulls tweets from

```
 $.fn.tweet = function(o){
    var s = $.extend({
      username: null,                           // [string or array] required unless using the 'query' option; one or more twitter screen names (use 'list' option for multiple names, where possible)
      list: null,                               // [string]   optional name of list belonging to username
      favorites: false,                         // [boolean]  display the user's favorites instead of his tweets
      query: null,                              // [string]   optional search query (see also: http://search.twitter.com/operators)
      avatar_size: null,                        // [integer]  height and width of avatar if displayed (48px max)
      count: 3,                                 // [integer]  how many tweets to display?
      fetch: null,                              // [integer]  how many tweets to fetch via the API (set this higher than 'count' if using the 'filter' option)
      page: 1,                                  // [integer]  which page of results to fetch (if count != fetch, you'll get unexpected results)
      retweets: true,                           // [boolean]  whether to fetch (official) retweets (not supported in all display modes)
      intro_text: null,                         // [string]   do you want text BEFORE your your tweets?
      outro_text: null,                         // [string]   do you want text AFTER your tweets?
      join_text:  null,                         // [string]   optional text in between date and tweet, try setting to "auto"
      auto_join_text_default: "I said,",        // [string]   auto text for non verb: "I said" bullocks
      auto_join_text_ed: "I",                   // [string]   auto text for past tense: "I" surfed
      auto_join_text_ing: "I am",               // [string]   auto tense for present tense: "I was" surfing
      auto_join_text_reply: "I replied to",     // [string]   auto tense for replies: "I replied to" @someone "with"
      auto_join_text_url: "I was looking at",   // [string]   auto tense for urls: "I was looking at" http:...
      loading_text: null,                       // [string]   optional loading text, displayed while tweets load
      refresh_interval: null,                   // [integer]  optional number of seconds after which to reload tweets
      twitter_url: "twitter.com",               // [string]   custom twitter url, if any (apigee, etc.)
      twitter_api_url: "api.twitter.com",       // [string]   custom twitter api url, if any (apigee, etc.)
      twitter_search_url: "search.twitter.com", // [string]   custom twitter search url, if any (apigee, etc.)
      template: "{avatar}{time}{join}{text}",   // [string or function] template used to construct each tweet <li> - see code for available vars
      comparator: function(tweet1, tweet2) {    // [function] comparator used to sort tweets (see Array.sort)
        return tweet2["tweet_time"] - tweet1["tweet_time"];
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you can (without hacking the plugin). I see no option for how far back to fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think maybe  count: does the trick as the larger number of tweets you fetch the farther back in time it goes, any thoughts??